# Scrollbars always visible in lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I want to show both scrollbars always visible as my content in table is too large row and column wise. How can I implement this? PLease find this figure to understand what I want.

[image]

Currently I am getting the horizontal sidebar accessible only when I reach at dead bottom of page but at that time my upper rows are not visible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your content within this tag. It enables the scrollbars based on the content length.

```
<div id="gee" class="slds slds-scrollable--x ">
```